# Swift Combine Framework - How to properly observe an array?

Tags: swift, combine

say I have an array of `Person` structs like this:

```swift
struct Person {
    var name: String
}

var persons = [Person(name: "A"), Person(name: "B"), Person(name: "C")]

let publisher = CurrentValueSubject<[Person], Never>(persons)

// subscribe to changes to the array
let subscription: AnyCancellable = publisher.sink { (persons) in
    print("The array has changed")
}

var currentPersons = publisher.value
currentPersons[0].name = "Changed"
publisher.send(currentPersons)
```

This works. It publishes every time anything in the array changes or if something is deleted or added.

But what if I wanted to additionally be able to subscribe to only one element in the array? Can I do that? I simply can't figure it out.

Comment: Make `Person` observable, by exposing its properties as `CurrentValueSubject`s

Comment: I tried that but it didn't quite work. I always end up having multiple copies of the `persons` array, instead of tracking one single instance of it

Comment: Wrap your array into a `Contacts` object or whatever, and make it the unique owner of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being referred to in an array does not magically place an object under observation. If you want to observe an object, you must observe that object, itself. Keeping such observations coordinated with the contents of some array is quite tricky, as you will need to start observing a new object when it is added and stop observing it when it is removed.

Comment: That's what I feared. I just hoped there was an easy way to do it. I've played around with it for four entire days without making it work. At this point, I consider going back to using classes as data models (I switched because I read structs are better for this). Tracking changes is more work inside the class but it just seems way easier to do these things without ending up with multiple copies of your data that are out-of-sync.

Comment: Well it’s not like this is a new problem. People have been doing this with KVO for years. See https://github.com/MaxGabriel/NSArrayKVO for a typical approach. You could adapt that to Combine (which after all can use KVO).